# What is 'deontic modality' really? How to tell it apart from epistemic?

Tags: semantics, modality

*I have to walk the dog* is deontic modality. *I had to walk the dog* is also deontic. But *I must have walked the dog* is epistemic (I am pretty sure) because the speaker means that, according to what they know and/or remember, they are convinced that they did walk the dog. They are not really conveying that they were under obligation to walk the dog.

Imagine this rule from a fictional card game:

1. a. *You must have created five-in-a-row of your color before your opponent does to win*

1. b. *You must have created five-in-a-row of your color before your opponent **did** to win*

I don't know how to analyse this, nor whether the type of modality in (a) is the same as the one in (b).

An obviously deontic statement of the same rule would be

2. *To win, you must create five-in-a-row of your color before your opponent does*

And an obviously epistemic statement of the same rule would be:

3. *You have won, which means that you must have created five in-a-row of your colour before your opponent did.*

Which modality is (1) really an instance of?

It looks like in English, *must have* + past participle is an epistemic construction. Is deontic/epistemic modality a description of the lexical (?) semantics (can a seemingly lexical item (not sure how better to describe this) like *must have* + past participle be enough to determine modality?), or something to do with the purpose of the statement?

Comment: To me, 1a is deontic while 1b is epistemic – the difference is as clear and unambiguous as that between 2 and 3. _Must have_ + past participle can be either; context usually disambiguates.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet actually looking at it now, I can see that 1b is entirely about the past: someone could have stated 1b after observing that someone else won. However 1a is about an event that has not happened, so I can see a difference between 1a and 1b. But why is 1a deontic?

Comment: Because it means the same thing as 2: “You have to be in a state of [having created five-in-a-row before your opponent] in order to win”. I would say that’s deontic.